# How to call a class from a cs file to update or save the session expired in database?

Tags: c#, sql, session-timeout

I have a class function as following & I would like to use this class to be called into my master page. Then, doing login & logout time saved of the page into my database.

```
namespace LogInLogOut
{
    public partial class LogInLogOut : System.Web.UI.Page
   {        
       public static void updateLogoutTime(string username, string pcname, string module)
        {
          String connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["VSConfigConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [Access]  set LogOutDate =  '" + DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "', LogOutTime =  '" + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + "' WHERE LoginID ='" + username + "' AND ModuleID = '" + module + "' AND comptname ='" + pcname + "' AND LogOutDate= ' '", connection);
            cmd.Connection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Connection.Close();
            cmd.Connection.Dispose();
        }
     }
}
```

Here is the code in master page for doing popup message, but I have no idea to write the call function for calling the upper class into my master page. Hope anyone can assist me for this problem. Thank you.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string csname = "timeoutWarning";
        Type cstype = this.GetType();
        if (!Page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered(cstype, csname))
        {
            string strconfirm = "<script>" +
                "window.setTimeout('SessionTimeOutHandler()', 10000);" +
                "function SessionTimeOutHandler() { " +
                "alert('Your login session is expired');" +
                "function(){ update(document.LogInLogOut('lblUserName.Text', 'lblComputerName.Text', 'UR')); } " + 
               "window.location='../login.aspx';" +
                " } </script>";
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, csname, strconfirm, false);
        }
}
```

Comment: Are you aware that you want to mix client-side and server-side code?

Comment: I think I didn't involved the server-side code. The upper is class function in a file named LogInLogOut.cs & downward is in another master page. Then, if I want to call & update my database just used LogInLogOut.LogInLogOut.updateLogoutTime(lblUserName.Text, lblComputerName.Text, "UR"). But now my problem is this updateupdateLogoutTime function doesn't save the correct logout time in my database, so how am I going to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call a server function like that in you javascript code.

To call a server function, you have to send a request to the server first. This is usually a Postback in asp.net.

If you do want to call a function like that, you have to mark it as a `WebMethod`. Asp.net will hide all the js that is needed to call the function.

This blog on [WebMethods](http://geekswithblogs.net/frankw/archive/2008/03/13/asp.net-ajax-callbacks-to-web-methods-in-aspx-pages.aspx) will get you started.

Your code should look like this:

```
 [System.Web.Services.WebMethod()] 
 [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()] 
 public void LogoutTime(string username, string pcname, string module)
    {
      String connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["VSConfigConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [Access]  set LogOutDate =  '" + DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "', LogOutTime =  '" + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + "' WHERE LoginID ='" + username + "' AND ModuleID = '" + module + "' AND comptname ='" + pcname + "' AND LogOutDate= ' '", connection);
        cmd.Connection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Connection.Close();
        cmd.Connection.Dispose();
    }
```

You can now call this function in javascript using `PageMethods`

```
PageMethods.LogoutTime('lblUserName.Text', 'lblComputerName.Text', 'UR', update);
```

You should put that function in your master page if you want it on all pages, not in a separate page.

Comment: Hi, it didn't shows any error message but still cannot saving the logout time in my database. Any other suggestion?

Comment: There was an error in reply, function names were different. Corrected it. `PageMethods.LogoutTime` should be available in javascript. Type this in a console or alert box and check the function exists.